# How to filter in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

```
location    state     data
WA          WA        3
WA          Seattle
```

I want to make it state only. After filtering, I want to store it in a new data frame such as

```
location    state     data
WA          WA        3
```

I am trying to solve this problem with dplyr and I tried

```
library(dplyr)

state_only <- filter(data, location == state)
```

But clearly it won't work. Is there any better method? Thanks!!

Comment: Works for me, what's the error you are getting?

Comment: Is `state` a column name? Please provide a reproducible example of your data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or, you were close with `dplyr`, try this:

```
library(dplyr)
location   <- c("WA", "WA")
state      <- c("WA", "Seattle")
data       <- c(3, NA)

mydataframe <- data.frame(location, state, data)                  

mydataframefiltered <- mydataframe %>% filter(state == "WA")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subset()` like this:

```
location <- c("WA", "WA", "WA")
state <- c("WA", "Seattle", "WA")
data <- c(3, 0, 2)

data <- data.frame(location = location, state = state, data = data)
data

subset(data, location == "WA" & state == "WA")
```

I've got this output:

```
  location   state data 
1       WA      WA    3  
2       WA Seattle    0 
3       WA      WA    2 

  location state data 
1       WA    WA    3 
3       WA    WA    2
```